# L key always brings command prompt window to front when open in background

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have an issue where if I have a command prompt open, either in the background or selected, I can't press the L key and get a normal lowercase L.

If I hit it in the command prompt window it just doesn't do anything, but if I hold Alt while pressing it, I can type it.
If I press it in any other open window, it always just switches to the command prompt window and brings it to the front. I can otherwise only really write with capital L's.

What is wrong with my computer? I only noticed this yesterday, and I haven't done anything that I can think of to change any hotkeys or anything in months.

What would help me fix this? Is this an issue anyone else has had?

-Mick

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution through trial and error, the permissions for the cmd.exe file in System32 was set to "Full Control" for the "Users" group. Changing this to "Read & Execute" seems to have fixed it.
Posting this for anyone else who could be experiencing this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing!